# Blazor Server - ProtectedLocalStorage Handling When Changing Docker Container?

Tags: asp.net, docker, blazor, local-storage, hosting

I am hosting a Blazor Server application using a Docker container. My project has a page that loads the following code from local storage, utilizing `OnAfterRednerAsync`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage ProtectedLocalStore

@code {
    public List<long>? upvoted = new List<long>();
    public List<long>? downvoted = new List<long>();
    private bool isConnected;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            isConnected = true;
            await LoadStateAsync();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadStateAsync()
    {
        var resultUpvoted = await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<List<long>>("upvoted");
        upvoted = resultUpvoted.Success ? resultUpvoted.Value : new List<long>();
        var resultDownvoted = await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<List<long>>("downvoted");
        upvoted = resultDownvoted.Success ? resultDownvoted.Value : new List<long>();
    }
}
```

Whenever I update my project, I update and run the new Docker container on my host machine. Any clients that have a value stored in `ProtectedLocalStorage` are not able to reload or view the page utilizing `ProtectedLocalStorage` again until they enter their browser tools and manually clear the local storage data.

UPDATE: The issue lies in the `await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<List<long>>("upvoted");` trying to cast encrypted values to <List>. When a new Docker container is created, it can no longer decrypt the existing local storage. Is it possible to have new containers be able to decrypt the existing local storage? Perhaps I could mount something that handles this process to my container so that it stays the same for each new container?

Comment: I deployed a blazer server app to a k8s pod and having similar issues with not being able to read local storage. I even tried switching from ProtectedStorage from Microsoft to Blazored.LocalStorage but no results. Any update on the above issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck being able to read the ProectedStorage when recreating the containers. However, Blazored.LocalStorage is working for me just fine. I don't like saving the data as plain text to the local storage but it is all that I can get to work for saving it across new containers.